# How can I compare the size of three arraylists in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have three `ArrayList`s, let's say `a`, `b`, and `c`, each of which contains some elements, and I want to compare their size to see if their sizes are equal, how can I do this? Is it like as follows:

```java
if (a.size() == b.size() == c.size()) {

  // do-something

}
```

Comment: `A.size()==B.size() && B.size()==C.size()`

Comment: The first comparison will yield a boolean. You could try comparing A to B then B to C. Something like this `A.length == B.length && B.length == C.length`.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (A.size() == B.size() && B.size() == C.size()) {
    // do something
}
```

Mathematically, if a=b and b=c then a=c. So, the above condition precisely filfils your requirement.

**Alternatively,**

```
if (A.size() == B.size()) {
    if (B.size() == C.size()) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Use this one-liner, or wrap this in a method to be called.

```
List
.of( listA , listB , listC )              // ⬅ Your list variables go here.
.stream()
.map( collection -> collection.size() )
.collect( Collectors.toSet() )
.size() 
== 1                                      // Returns `true` if your lists are all the same size. Returns `false` if different sizes.
```

## Details

### `Set` from a `List` of the lists’ sizes

Here is a one-liner.

```
if(
    new TreeSet< Integer > (
        List.of( 
            listA.size() , 
            listB.size() , 
            listC.size()
        )
    )
    .size() == 1 
)
{…}
```

We collect the sizes of each of the lists, putting the sizes into a `Set< Integer >`. Sets eliminate duplicates. So after adding all the sizes, we should have a single value in the set.

For example, if all the lists are the same size, with a count of seven elements, then we end up with a single element set, [ 7 ]. On the other hand, if some of the lists had seven elements, and some had eight, then the resulting set of list sizes would have two elements [ 7 , 8 ] rather than one element.

#### Complete example

Here is a complete example.

```
package work.basil.example

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class ListSizes
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        List listA = List.of( "Dog" , "Cat" , "Rabbit" ); 
        List listB = List.of( "Dog" , "Cat" , "Bird" );
        List listC = List.of( "Elephant" , "Giraffe" , "Hippo" );

        if(
            new TreeSet< Integer > (
                List.of( 
                    listA.size() , 
                    listB.size() , 
                    listC.size()
                )
            )
            .size() == 1 
        )
        { System.out.println( "Same size." ) ; }
        else
        { System.out.println( "Different sizes." ) ; }

    }
}
```

See that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/meuOND). You can fork that code within IdeOne.com to try deleting or adding items to any of the lists.

> Same size.

By the way, you might notice how [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) has kicked-in, converting the `int` primitive returns by `List::size` into an `Integer` object to be passed into the `List.of` method call. I am a bit surprised that worked without needing to wrap the `List::size` calls in `Integer.valueOf` call.

### Make a method, passing your collections whose sizes need comparing

We could put this code in a method. Use the varargs feature of Java, you would pass any number of `Collection` objects. Their sizes would then be compared.

```
Boolean sameSize ( Collection... arguments )
{
    List < Integer > sizes = new ArrayList <>( arguments.length );
    for ( Collection collection : arguments )
    {
        sizes.add( collection.size() );
    }
    return ( new TreeSet < Integer >( sizes ).size() == 1 );
}
```

Let's try using the method.

```
List listA = List.of( "Dog" , "Cat" );
List listB = List.of( "Dog" , "Cat" , "Bird" );
List listC = List.of( "Elephant" , "Giraffe" , "Hippo" );

Boolean sameSize = this.sameSize( listA , listB , listC );
System.out.println( "sameSize = " + sameSize );
```

See that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/FF3WH4).

#### Stream & lambda

We could shorten that method by using stream and lambda syntax.

```
Boolean sameSize ( Collection... arguments )
{
    List< Integer > sizes = Arrays.stream( arguments ).map( collection -> collection.size() ).collect( Collectors.toList());
    return ( new TreeSet < Integer >( sizes ).size() == 1 );
}
```

We could even shorten it to a one-liner.

```
Boolean sameSize ( Collection... arguments )
{
    return (
            new TreeSet < Integer >(
                    Arrays
                    .stream( arguments )
                    .map( collection -> collection.size() )
                    .collect( Collectors.toList() )
            ).size() == 1
    );
}
```

Which means we could also use this one-liner directly, without putting in a named method. And doing so would make it a bit easier to pass our list arguments, as we no longer need to call `size()` on each list as we did in the code at top of this Answer.

```
Boolean sameSize = new TreeSet < Integer >(
        List
                .of( listA , listB , listC )  // ⬅ Your list variables go here.
                .stream()
                .map( collection -> collection.size() )
                .collect( Collectors.toList() )
).size() == 1;
```

We could simplify further by using a `Collector` that makes a `Set`. No need to make a list and feed that into the constructor of a `Set`. The stream & lambda can feed our size results directly into a set.

```
Boolean sameSize =
        List
                .of( listA , listB , listC )  // ⬅ Your list variables go here.
                .stream()
                .map( collection -> collection.size() )
                .collect( Collectors.toSet() )
                .size() == 1;
```